# zookeeper getChildren watcher can't get subnode's NodeCreated event

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper

use getChildren("/abc", watcher), when i create a subnode "/abc/hi", the watcher only recieved NodeChildrenChanged event.

A client create "/abc/hi"

how B client  recieve NodeCreated event?

thx

Answer (score 1):

*NodeCreated* event is valid for only [exists()](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.1/api/org/apache/zookeeper/ZooKeeper.html#exists%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.zookeeper.Watcher%29) function not for [getChildren()](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.1/api/org/apache/zookeeper/ZooKeeper.html#getChildren%28java.lang.String,%20org.apache.zookeeper.Watcher%29)

You get only *NodeChildrenChanged* event for any changes in the child nodes when you do a `getChildren()` and keep a watch.